# Why does not onChange event produced?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, checkbox

Assume, we have following markup:

```
<form>
    <button type="button" id="all">check all</button>
    <button type="button" id="none">check none</button>
    <input type="checkbox" value="one" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="two" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="three" />
</form>
```

And following JavaScript code:

```
(function($, document) {
    $('#all').on('click', function() {
         $('input', $(this).parent()).prop('checked', 'checked');
    });
    $('#none').on('click', function() {
        $('input', $(this).parent()).removeProp('checked');
    });

    $('input').on('change', function() {
        alert(this.value);
    });
}(jQuery, document));
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/inst/h7kyq/1/)

Why doesn't input's onChange event handler executed when we click on the any of the button?

Comment: When using `.prop()` on a boolean property, use a boolean value. `.prop('checked', true)` or `.prop('checked', false)`

Comment: Don't use  removeProp() unless you want to permanently remove the property as you cannot use/add that property again to the element.  Read http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/  As you can tell in your fiddle once you click the remove all the select all no longer functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any programatic change (changes from script) to an input element will not trigger `onchange` event..

Alternatively, you should trigger change event manually when you change the status/value.

See below,

```
$('input', $(this).parent()).removeProp('checked').change();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/h7kyq/4/

Answer (score 3):

Events are not fired when the change occurs in javascript.  You will need to fire the event yourself:

```
$('input', $(this).parent()).removeProp('checked').change();
```

Comment: This is intentional behavior.  Events are not fired when changed by code, because it could unintentionally trigger code we'd rather not run unless the user is the one making the change.